# MySQL aggregated join?

Tags: mysql, sql, correlated-subquery, subquery

I have a table with schema: Table(rank, score).
I need to make a query that gets the average of the scores that has a rank that is greater than the current rank for each rank.
Query(rank, average_score_of_greater_ranks).

I've tried something like:

```
select `rank`, avg_score_of_greater_ranks
from Table t1
join (SELECT AVG(Revenue_Amount) as avg_score_of_greater_ranks
                        from Table t2
                        where t1.rank > t2.rank) as temp
order by `rank`
```

but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using? (`select version();`)

Comment: the version is 8.0.24

Comment: What is the relationship between `rank` and `score`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to make a query that gets the average of the scores that has a rank that is greater than the current rank for each rank. Query(rank, average_of_lower_ranks).

Assuming that the rank is based on the score, this is just a cumulative average.  For the average of scores greater than or equal to the given score:

```
select t1.*,
       avg(`rank`) over (order by `rank` desc)
from Table t1;
```

It is a bit tricker if you just want the average of those strictly larger.  Assuming `rank` is an integer, you can use:

```
select t1.*,
       avg(`rank`) over (order by `rank`
                         range between 1 following and unbounded following
                        ) as avg_rank_greater
from t1;
```

If the ranking is unrelated to the score, you can replace the `order by rank` in the above expressions with `order by score`.